# How to find wordpress db schema changes when upgrading from 4.9 to 5.2

Tags: plugins, upgrade

When I upgrade from 4.9 to 5.2, the installer will say the database would need be upgraded, however, before doing so, it is possible to check what has changed?

Answer (score 0):

In `wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php` there is a function called [`dbDelta`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.4/src/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php#L2525).

If you'll pass `FALSE` as second argument and `''` (empty string) as first, then you'll get the list of all changes, that should be made to database (but none of them will be executed).

You can also find the new structure of DB in `wp-admin/includes/schema.php` file of the new version, so you can do the comparison manually.